# BATCH write hebrew into text file

Tags: batch-file, dos

i want to write "`אבג`" into txt file


when im typing "`echo אבג >> c:\test.txt`" in the cmd window it looks like:


https://i.stack.imgur.com/A02rD.png


and when im pressing Enter the text file content is:

```
€‚
```

how can i write hebrew text into text file?

Comment: What is your exact OS you're on? I was thinking chcp could help: http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/chcp.mspx?mfr=true  . Unfortunately it doesn't say it supports an hebrew codepage...

Answer (score 1):

One way to workaround this is to print the letters to html file [by getting their entities](http://archive.tlt.psu.edu/suggestions/international/bylanguage/hebrewchart.html):

```
@echo off
set gimel= ^^^&#1488;
set kaf= ^^^&#1499;
set alef= ^^^&#1488;
setlocal 
echo  ^<html^>  ^<body^> %gimel% %kaf% %alef% ^</body^> ^</html^> > herb.html
```